# JSON parsing: Unexpected Token error when using with Datatable

Tags: ajax, json, datatable, datatables

I basically want to implement DataTables AJAX source example given in the link https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html. everytime I run it, I get the error **http://datatables.net/tn/1.** So I googled about this error and got to know that it has Invalid JSON response. So I copy pasted my text (arr.txt) code in JsonLint which gives the error **Unexpected token.** I am really curious about this error. Kindly help me to fix it. Thanks in advance !

This is my arr.txt. (in Json) (I copy pasted this in notepad and saved it as .txt)

```
 {
      "aaData": [
        [
          "Trident",
          "Internet Explorer 4.0",
          "Win 95+",
          "4",
          "X"
        ],
        [
          "Trident",
          "Internet Explorer 5.0",
          "Win 95+",
          "5",
          "C"
        ],
        [
          "Trident",
          "Internet Explorer 5.5",
          "Win 95+",
          "5.5",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Trident",
          "Internet Explorer 6",
          "Win 98+",
          "6",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Trident",
          "Internet Explorer 7",
          "Win XP SP2+",
          "7",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Trident",
          "AOL browser (AOL desktop)",
          "Win XP",
          "6",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Firefox 1.0",
          "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
          "1.7",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Firefox 1.5",
          "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
          "1.8",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Firefox 2.0",
          "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
          "1.8",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Firefox 3.0",
          "Win 2k+ / OSX.3+",
          "1.9",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Camino 1.0",
          "OSX.2+",
          "1.8",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Camino 1.5",
          "OSX.3+",
          "1.8",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Netscape 7.2",
          "Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2",
          "1.7",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Netscape Browser 8",
          "Win 98SE+",
          "1.7",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Netscape Navigator 9",
          "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
          "1.8",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Mozilla 1.0",
          "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
          1,
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Mozilla 1.1",
          "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
          1.1,
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Mozilla 1.2",
          "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
          1.2,
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Mozilla 1.3",
          "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
          1.3,
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Mozilla 1.4",
          "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
          1.4,
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Mozilla 1.5",
          "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
          1.5,
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Mozilla 1.6",
          "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
          1.6,
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Mozilla 1.7",
          "Win 98+ / OSX.1+",
          1.7,
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Mozilla 1.8",
          "Win 98+ / OSX.1+",
          1.8,
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Seamonkey 1.1",
          "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
          "1.8",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Epiphany 2.20",
          "Gnome",
          "1.8",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Webkit",
          "Safari 1.2",
          "OSX.3",
          "125.5",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Webkit",
          "Safari 1.3",
          "OSX.3",
          "312.8",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Webkit",
          "Safari 2.0",
          "OSX.4+",
          "419.3",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Webkit",
          "Safari 3.0",
          "OSX.4+",
          "522.1",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Webkit",
          "OmniWeb 5.5",
          "OSX.4+",
          "420",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Webkit",
          "iPod Touch / iPhone",
          "iPod",
          "420.1",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Webkit",
          "S60",
          "S60",
          "413",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Presto",
          "Opera 7.0",
          "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
          "-",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Presto",
          "Opera 7.5",
          "Win 95+ / OSX.2+",
          "-",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Presto",
          "Opera 8.0",
          "Win 95+ / OSX.2+",
          "-",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Presto",
          "Opera 8.5",
          "Win 95+ / OSX.2+",
          "-",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Presto",
          "Opera 9.0",
          "Win 95+ / OSX.3+",
          "-",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Presto",
          "Opera 9.2",
          "Win 88+ / OSX.3+",
          "-",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Presto",
          "Opera 9.5",
          "Win 88+ / OSX.3+",
          "-",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Presto",
          "Opera for Wii",
          "Wii",
          "-",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Presto",
          "Nokia N800",
          "N800",
          "-",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Presto",
          "Nintendo DS browser",
          "Nintendo DS",
          "8.5",
          "C/A<sup>1</sup>"
        ],
        [
          "KHTML",
          "Konqureror 3.1",
          "KDE 3.1",
          "3.1",
          "C"
        ],
        [
          "KHTML",
          "Konqureror 3.3",
          "KDE 3.3",
          "3.3",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "KHTML",
          "Konqureror 3.5",
          "KDE 3.5",
          "3.5",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Tasman",
          "Internet Explorer 4.5",
          "Mac OS 8-9",
          "-",
          "X"
        ],
        [
          "Tasman",
          "Internet Explorer 5.1",
          "Mac OS 7.6-9",
          "1",
          "C"
        ],
        [
          "Tasman",
          "Internet Explorer 5.2",
          "Mac OS 8-X",
          "1",
          "C"
        ],
        [
          "Misc",
          "NetFront 3.1",
          "Embedded devices",
          "-",
          "C"
        ],
        [
          "Misc",
          "NetFront 3.4",
          "Embedded devices",
          "-",
          "A"
        ],
        [
          "Misc",
          "Dillo 0.8",
          "Embedded devices",
          "-",
          "X"
        ],
        [
          "Misc",
          "Links",
          "Text only",
          "-",
          "X"
        ],
        [
          "Misc",
          "Lynx",
          "Text only",
          "-",
          "X"
        ],
        [
          "Misc",
          "IE Mobile",
          "Windows Mobile 6",
          "-",
          "C"
        ],
        [
          "Misc",
          "PSP browser",
          "PSP",
          "-",
          "C"
        ],
        [
          "Other browsers",
          "All others",
          "-",
          "-",
          "U"
        ]
      ]
    }
```

### This is my index.html:-

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0-beta.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/505bef35b56/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.css"> -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="NewFile.css">
</head>
<body>
<form><input type="text" id="myInputTextField"></form>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SECTION</th>
                <th>REPORT NAME</th>
                <th>CONTACT PERSON</th>
                <th>LINK TO DOWNLOAD</th>
                <th>METRICS USED</th>
                <!-- <th>Salary</th> -->
            </tr>
        </thead>


    </table> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0-beta.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "arr.txt"
        } );
    } );



  </script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The JSON looks fine. Are you sure the server is sending what you think it is in the response?

Comment: No ! I just can't figure out where is the error ! Totally helpless !

Answer (score 1):

Add the following option to your datatable, which will allow you to examine what has been retuned from the server and do further processing if required before Datatables tries to use it:

```
 "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {

                 alert(json); /*break here to examine json returned from server*/

                 /*Do any further processing required*/

                 fnCallback(json); /*continue with the call back*/
            });
        },
```